# Calculating playoff win probability for fantasy football league

Tags: probability

I'm trying to make a spreadsheet to determine the likelihood of each team in my fantasy football league advancing through each stage of the playoffs, and running into some numbers that won't add up. I'm not a statistician, so it's probably a very simple issue, but I can't seem to figure it out!

We have an 8 team league, with 5 teams still vying for 4 playoff spots and one more non-playoff game to play. I have a very simple model for calculating head-to-head win probability (based on average points scored), and using that I've found the likelihood that each of the 5 teams gets one of these 4 playoff spots. Those probabilities all add up to 400%, so that's good! I've also got probabilities that each team is either the 1, 2, 3, or 4 seeds, and similarly these probabilities all add up to 400% in total, and for each team they add up to the team's likelihood of making the playoffs.

| Team | Make playoff% | Seed 1% | Seed 2% | Seed 3% | Seed 4% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T1 | 100.0% | 50.7% | 28.0% | 16.8% | 4.5% |
| T2 | 100.0% | 49.3% | 28.7% | 17.3% | 4.6% |
| T3 | 92.5% | 0.0% | 22.7% | 30.2% | 39.6% |
| T4 | 79.0% | 0.0% | 20.6% | 28.2% | 30.2% |
| T5 | 28.5% | 0.0% | 0.0% | 7.5% | 21.0% |

So far so good (at least, I think). My trouble starts when I try to calculate the probability of each team reaching the finals game. In the first round of the playoffs the 1 and 4 seeds will be matched up along with the 2 and 3 seeds, and the winners of each matchup go on to the finals game. My thought was that all I need is to calculate win probabilities for every matchup, multiplied by the probability that that matchup occurs, and then sum the results for every permutation.

So for instance, the matchup between T1 as 1 seed (T1.1) vs T2 as 4 seed (T2.4) has a likelihood of 50.7% * 4.6% = 2.3%. T1 beats T2 50.7% of the time, so I calculate the likelihood of T1 advancing to the finals via this specific matchup as 2.3% * 50.7% = 1.2%. I made a table including all possible permutations (omitting the permutations involving multiplication by 0%). I'll use the shorthand of "Team a as i seed plays Team b as j seed = Ta.i x Tb.j"

| Matchup | Matchup% | Win% | Matchup advance% |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| T1.1xT2.4 | 2.3% | 50.7% | 1.2% |
| T1.1xT3.4 | 20.1% | 50.1% | 10.1% |
| T1.1xT4.4 | 15.3% | 50.4% | 7.7% |
| T1.1xT5.4 | 10.7% | 50.9% | 5.4% |
| T1.2xT2.3 | 4.8% | 50.7% | 2.5% |
| T1.2xT3.3 | 8.4% | 50.1% | 4.2% |
| T1.2xT4.3 | 7.9% | 50.4% | 4.0% |
| T1.2xT5.3 | 2.1% | 50.9% | 1.1% |
| T1.3xT2.2 | 4.8% | 50.7% | 2.5% |
| T1.3xT3.2 | 3.8% | 50.1% | 1.9% |
| T1.3xT4.2 | 3.5% | 50.4% | 1.8% |
| T1.4xT2.1 | 2.2% | 50.7% | 1.1% |
| SUM | 86.0% |  | 43.4% |

So for Team 1 I find a 43.4% chance of advancing to the finals - but this is also where I run into trouble, because when I do this for every team and add up the chance of each team reaching the finals it comes out to 131.7%, which shouldn't make sense I don't think. Two teams can reach the finals, so it should add up to 200%, right?

Going back to the table above, it seems like the problem might stem somehow from the way I'm calculating the matchups. Team 1 has a 100% chance of making the playoffs, so the sum of all of the matchup probabilities should be 100%, not 86%.

What am I doing wrong? Are there dependent probabilities I'm not thinking about?

Thanks!

Comment: Where are you getting the win probabilities? It seems you re-use the 50.7% probability of T1 being seed 1 as the same probability of T1 beating T2, but I don't see the rationale for that. The "Win %" column doesn't make sense to me - why is T1 more likely to beat T2 as S4 than T3 as S4, despite the fact that T2 is better than T3 and more likely to be in a higher seed?

Comment: Yes - the probability that T2 ends up 4th is not independent of T1 finishing 1st. To get the probability of the matchup T1.1xT2.4 needs to be calculated as...
$$P(T1.1xT2.4) = 50.7\% \times P(\text{T2 is S4 Given that T1 is S1})$$

Comment: @NuclearHoagie sorry I know that part is confusing - I didn't reuse the value, it's just that the win probability of T1 vs T2 happens to be the same as the probability of T1 being the 1 seed. The win probability (and the values in the Win% column) come from the pythagorean win formula ala baseball, and the reason T1 is more likely to beat T3 than T2 is that T3 scored more points, which is all the win model is based on.

Comment: @WW1 I think that's gotta be it, didn't think about that. Thanks!